# (beginner) cant find symbol for printf statement

Tags: java, printf

Here is my code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class assignment6 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    double count = 1;
    double kilo = 1;
    double pound = 2.2;

    System.out.println("Kilograms    Pounds");
    while(count<100)
    {
      System.out.printf((kilo*count)     %d, pound*kilo);
      System.out.println("");
      count++;
    }
  }
}
```

The error is on the printf statement on the %d part. It says `cannot find symbol`, why isn't this printf working?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like below. For double you should use %f. %d is for integers.

```
public class Assignment6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double count = 1;
        double kilo = 1;
        double pound = 2.2;

        System.out.println("Kilograms    Pounds");
        while(count<100)
        {
          System.out.printf("%f  %f", (kilo*count), (pound*kilo));
          System.out.println("");
          count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ohh I get it now. Thank you so much. I didn't know you could use two placeholders and use commas to separate them into different sections

Comment: Glad that I could help you!